# Object.create and Prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype, object-create

When I use object.create to create a new object like so,

```
o = {x:1,y:2};
p = Object.create(o);
```

I'm under the impression that o becomes the prototype of p and inherits all its methods.

Then why, when I try

```
print(p.prototype);
```

the output is undefined? o is well-defined!!

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Only **functions** have a `prototype` property *<sup>[ES5]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.2).

`p` references `o` through the internal `[[Prototype]]` property, which was accessible in some browsers with [`__proto__` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), but is now deprecated.

You can get a reference to the prototype of an object with [`Object.getPrototypeOf` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === o // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `o` becomes the prototype of `p` means `o` is the prototype of `p`'s constructor.

```
console.log(p.constructor.prototype);
```

---

```
var o = {x:1,y:2};
var p = Object.create(o);
```

You could image above as below:

```
var o = {x:1,y:2};
function constructor_of_p(){};
constructor_of_p.prototype = o;
var p = new constructor_of_p();
```